edmx files are not getting embedded into the output directory
I have a solution with projects that some / one of them (let's call that PROJECT-A) includes Entity Framework (version 4) with an .edmx file.
This file is not embedded into the output directory in the build process when using dotnet build command.
As a result, I get a runtime error:

System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource

I can not run MSBuild CLI command on that project because some other projects (let's call one of them PROJECT-B) - referenced by PROJECT-A - is a SDK project and as such cannot be built using a msbuild command.
What can I do in order to solve this problem, where the final result is a successful build / publish process and an .edmx file which is embedded in the output directory?
